# How do i debug a programmatically injected JS file in google chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

i'm injecting a js file to every page in google chrome via

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {  
  chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:"js/content.js"},function(resultArr){
    console.log(resultArr);
  });  
});
```

**content.js**

```
console.log("hello stackoverflow");
```

I can see `hello stackoverflow` printed in the console of the webpage. But i'm not able to find the source file, so i can debug it. Any idea how?

Comment: Have you tried `Tools > Developer tools > Sources`?

Comment: Yeah. i used to check here for js files injected through `manifest.json`, but can't find this. maybe becoz its injected programmatically.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the `debugger` keyword. This is like inserting a breakpoint into your JS code

so in **content.js**

```
debugger;
console.log("hello stackoverflow");
```

Comment: @shahalpk you're welcome. Just remember to delete all your `debugger` lines when you're done!

Comment: `debugger` is a statement. The semicolon will be added by the [Automatic Semicolon Insertion](http://es5.github.io/x7.html#x7.9) rules, but it's wrong to suggest that a semicolon has to be omitted.

Comment: @RobW I had a problem previously with the semi-colon (debugger never stopped code execution). I just tried it again in jsFiddle though and it worked so I guess my previous issue was unrelated. I've updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone who stumbles upon this, there is a cleaner solution.

Just add

```
//@ sourceURL = your_injected_file.js
```

at the top of your_injected_file.js. After first injection of the script, the script should be visible under Developer tools > Sources > Content Scripts.

Comment: It didn't work for me. I guess this depends on the type of JavaScript injection. It can be injected without actually having a file.

Comment: For debugging inline JavaScript, Chrome inspect element should work.

Comment: I don't get your point, Matt. The injected javascript is not binded to any of the page's elements.

What do you mean with "inline javascript", in the context of javascript injection? The two ways I know how to inject it is using a browser extension (for automatic injection) or using the Developer Console (console tab, for manual injection). Then just add code that manipulates DOM elements using the document object. In my case, to add styles.

I tried your suggestion, but yet I can't find the injected script using Windows key + P and writing the sourceURL either.

Answer (score 0):

You can type following inside your console:
angular.element($0).scope()

Then you can search for the function you want to debug by expanding the result.

You will see FunctionLocation link as one of the child under the node. 
You can click on the link to open file where you can put debug point and debug.